# Mutiple scrollbars are showing in thirdparty application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, iframe

I have a situation where am facing in my application dual scrollbars . Have added scrollbar in container level (header level ) and when i click on my thirdparty link it will launch other application in same window in a iframe .

Now the problem is I am getting scrollbar for iframe also along with header div scrollbar . if i hide header scrollbar it will impact my actual application before thirdparty .

Icould not get my thirdparty application opened from DIV . So I am trying iframe . Can some one help .

How to hide iframe scroll bar or using same div fro thirdparty application as well....I have tried scrollbar="No" , overflow:hidden for hiding iframe scrollbar . None of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css code to hide scrollbar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eo0hv7t/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I cant give this at css level bcoz it impacts entire application , have to embed in html .whenever thirdparty launches i have to hide div scrollbar . How can i add this in html ?

Comment: You want to hide scrollbar when user clicks on a link?

Comment: i want to hide scrollbar when i am landed into thirdparty application . here i will have DIV and Iframe . Now the problem is DIV has own scrollbar and iframe has own scrollbar . DIV has just a header . If i hide this it would be enough .

Comment: Browser is assuming there is overflow content in iframe so DIV also giving scroll

Comment: If you show me a fiddle i can understand you better and fix it.
You have a div containing a header and an iframe including an iframe.html.
I assume you want to hide one of those scrollbars, so you can add those css codes to iframe.html.
If you give me some codes or a fiddle i can fix it

Comment: <div class="container" ><h> header </h><div ng-show="Iframe" >
  <iframe  id="testId" 
    name="testFrame" src="about:blank" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none" width="100%" frameborder="10" > </iframe>
 </div></div>       Now this iframe embeded in my final page and when i click on thirdparty link i will move out of my control and landed into thirdparty . here i have header div which container one will have scroll bar . If i hide this here that would be enough .